# How to move a std::vector into a raw array in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector, move-semantics

How can I move the contents of `std::vector` into an array safely without copying or iterating over all elements?

```cpp
void someFunc(float* arr, std::size_t& size)
{
   std::vector<float> vec(5, 1.5f);
   // do something with the data

   size = vec.size();
   arr = vec.data(); // this doesn't work, as at the end of the function the data in std::vector will be deallocated

}

main()
{
   float* arr;
   std::size_t size{0};

   someFunc(arr, size);

   // do something with the data
   delete [] arr;
}
```

How can I assign my array with the data in `std::vector` and making sure that deallocation will not be called on `std::vector`?  Or maybe any other ideas to go around this?

Comment: What is your goal? Why not keep the vector and use its `.data()`?

Comment: You can use a `vector<T>` on legacy functions that take a `T*`.  As stated, just use the `data()` member.  There is no need to shuffle between vector and a regular array, if this is what you were intending to do.

Comment: Well, I actually can stick with std::vector, but still need to use some old code that consider the data to be in raw array. And I really don't want to edit or rewrite the old code

Comment: @BoboFeugo -- But all you need is to pass `data()` to the top-level "old code" function, and the rest is all an array, the old code has no idea the data was being managed by a vector.  Have you ever used `data()`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That only works if the "old code" doesn't want to assume ownership.

Comment: As I know `data()` will return a pointer to const data, but I need to modify the data

Comment: @BoboFeugo [only from a `const vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data). From a mutable vector you get a pointer-to-mutable

Comment: @MaxLanghof The only thing I can think of that the old code would have done with ownership that would totally mess this up is to call `delete[]` on the pointer (which is a bad design to being with).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie or `free()`, or `delete`, or `lib_MyBadOlLib_Free()`

Comment: @BoboFeugo You are thinking of `std::string::c_str()`, where the return value is `const`.  Not so for a non-const vector.

Comment: I want to do exactly this because I am using a library (lodepng) that reads a file into a vector. I want to return a unique_ptr that wraps the vector's data, which could be very large (or I want to repeat the operation many times; either way I don't want to allocate, read, then copy, nor do I want to return the vector itself, though this is likely what I'll settle on).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can't.**

A vector owns its buffer. You cannot steal it.

You will have to copy/move the elements individually, optionally using a helper algorithm that does the iteration for you (`std::copy`/`std::move`).

(Also note that, since your element type is just `float`, a move here *is* a copy.)

(Also note that this `std::move`, the algorithm, is not the same as `std::move`, the rvalue cast.)

---

Consider whether you *really* need to do this. You can treat the vector's data as an array using `vec.data()` whenever you need to, as long as you keep the vector alive. Surely that's better than sacrificing RAII?

Comment: So how do you use std::move for this purpose?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move Though, since you only have floats, "move" will really just be a copy.

Comment: actually the `move` I asked for is not the one from the standard algorithm, instead i wanted something like `move-semantics` or a shallow copy. But as the most comments stated that it's not possible, i may have to change my implementation!

Comment: @Bobo Indeed, you're asking how to move (or "steal") the vector's internal buffer - you can't do that. Well, you can steal it into another vector, but that doesn't help you ;) The `std::move` I'm talking about is for the "individual" elements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit why not the other way around, where you have the vector steal from a pre-existing allocation? This answer is pretty defeatist

Answer (score 0):

This would have been handy for me for stealing a "typed" vector contents into an "untyped" vector.

This is what I want to do:

```
std::vector<uint8_t>­one;
std::vector<V> other = std::move(one);
```

When I know that the contents are exactly what I expect (there is a runtime type info field)

I would use this to do 'move semantics' between an untyped
and a typed class where part of the underlying representation
is in a vector - just in the typed case it is vector of Vs.

Think of it as a different "view" of the data. In general cases the data
is untyped as there are special edge-cases, but after handling them via
branching it would be handy to handle the "normal" cases type safe ways..

I see I can implement this behaviour if I throw out std::vector and do
my implementation using direct pointer arithmetic as then I can access
that in move construction, but I would love to not give up on vectors...

Just wanted to add this to show what kind of rationale might be behind
these kind of questions and I think sometimes it is valid